# Implement Word Spell check in Windows Form App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, office-2007, spell-checking

I have an In-house windows form app that I would like to use Spell Checking in.  Everyone has Office 2007 installed so I shouldn't have an issue there but I am having trouble getting this to fully work.

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Refraction.Spelling
{
    public static class SpellCheckers
    {
        public static string CheckSpelling(string text)
        {
            Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
 object nullobj = Missing.Value;
                object template = Missing.Value;
                object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
                object documentType = Missing.Value;
                object visible = true;
                object optional = Missing.Value;
            object savechanges = false;
            Word._Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref template, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);

        doc.Words.First.InsertBefore(text);
        Word.ProofreadingErrors errors = doc.SpellingErrors;

        var ecount = errors.Count;
        doc.CheckSpelling(ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 
            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 
            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional);
        object first = 0;
        object last = doc.Characters.Count - 1;
        var results = doc.Range(ref first, ref last).Text;
        doc.Close(ref savechanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
        app.Quit(ref savechanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

        return results;
    }
}

}
```

I use this like so:

```
memDirectionsToAddress.Text = SpellCheckers.CheckSpelling(memDirectionsToAddress.Text);
```

Now this successfully pops up the SpellCheck Dialog from Word and detects any misspelled words<strike>but I cannot get it to make the corrections in the WinForm app</strike>.

<strike>Also, it leaves this "Shell" of a Word Doc open with the corrected text. How do I not show that or at least make it go away?</strike>

Two things:

- First, though the "shell" closes it
  Flashes everytime.  Any solutions to
  that?
- Second, the Spell Check Dialog does
  not appear on TOP, what can I set to
  correct that?

Thanks

Comment: Additional question:  Is there any reason NOT to make this STATIC?

Comment: If you don't make it static, you could keep references to a specific document and/or the word application.  That would help you avoid the startup costs of a new app or document.  (You may be able to keep a document open but invisible, by playing with the Visible property or the app and always starting a new app.)

Comment: the problem is that if I don't do a `app.Close()` at the end then a Shell of Word stays open....

Comment: I had to change `object visible = true;` and add `app.ShowMe();`  The answer below helped guide me, that is why I accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next steps would be:

1. Pull the corrected text back out of the document.
2. Close the document.  (If there's only one document open in Word, you may want to close or hide the Word application.)
3. Return the corrected text to the calling function.

More info:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ac899e2d-5c2f-4ea9-ada2-b03aa4773664
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Globalking/fileAccessingusingcsharp02242006050207AM/fileAccessingusingcsharp.aspx?ArticleID=44e79e38-0cdc-4e5e-8574-63572d8cc112

Comment: Thanks, so it actually corrects the text in the "hidden" word doc and then I need to grab that.  Any hints on how I grab the text back out?

Comment: Use the selection object.  Do a "select all", then read the text out of the selection.

Comment: see my comment's on Question for FULL answer

Answer (score 0):

I have an old script for this where the required features are all invoked so no DLL ref are required for word itself:

```
internal class SpellChecker
{
    public SpellChecker()
    {
    }

    public static string Check(string text)
    {
        bool flag;
        string str = text;
        flag = (text == null ? true : !(text != ""));
        bool flag1 = flag;
        if (!flag1)
        {
            Type typeFromProgID = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeFromProgID);
            object[] objArray = new object[1];
            object obj1 = typeFromProgID.InvokeMember("Documents", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, null);
            object obj2 = obj1.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj1, null);
            object obj3 = obj2.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveWindow", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj2, null);
            objArray[0] = 0;
            obj3.GetType().InvokeMember("WindowState", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj3, objArray);
            object[] objArray1 = new object[] { -2000, -2000 };
            obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Move", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, objArray1);
            objArray[0] = "Spell Check";
            obj3.GetType().InvokeMember("Caption", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj3, objArray);
            object obj4 = typeFromProgID.InvokeMember("Selection", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, null);
            objArray[0] = text;
            obj4.GetType().InvokeMember("TypeText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj4, objArray);
            objArray[0] = 6;
            obj4.GetType().InvokeMember("HomeKey", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj4, objArray);
            object obj5 = obj2.GetType().InvokeMember("SpellingErrors", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj2, null);
            int num = (int)obj5.GetType().InvokeMember("Count", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj5, null);
            flag1 = num <= 0;
            if (flag1)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Spellcheck is correct");
            }
            else
            {
                obj3.GetType().InvokeMember("Activate", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj3, null);
                objArray1 = new object[] { -5000, -5000 };
                obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Move", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, objArray1);
                objArray[0] = true;
                obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj, objArray);
                obj2.GetType().InvokeMember("CheckSpelling", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj2, null);
                objArray[0] = true;
                obj2.GetType().InvokeMember("Saved", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj2, objArray);
                object obj6 = obj2.GetType().InvokeMember("Content", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj2, null);
                str = obj6.GetType().InvokeMember("Text", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj6, null).ToString();
                str = str.Trim();
            }
            flag1 = obj == null;
            if (!flag1)
            {
                objArray[0] = true;
                obj2.GetType().InvokeMember("Saved", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj2, objArray);
                obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Quit", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);
            }
        }
        string str1 = str;
        return str1;
    }
}
```

Just feed it the text and it will return with any corrections you approve.